# Android JUnit test method hang if more than one test methods exist in the test class

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I am writing an Android `JUnit` test for one application. I extend `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` and have more than one test methods in my test class. I do not use Robotium - just a simple Android JUnit test.
When I run the test methods in one go, the first one passes, the next one hangs. If I run them separately, all pass. What happens in my tests is that in each test method I start the `Activity_Under_Test` with `getActivity()`, then do something, which starts another activity and the one under test is automatically destroyed. I try to destroy the newly started activity as well (it was captured by monitor), but it stays open on my device and the next test method hangs on `getActivity()`. Can you please tell me how I can make the next test methods start the `Activity_Under_Test` properly? I cannot give actual code, but here is some sample of what I am doing:

```
public class Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2< Activity_Under_Test> {

    ... // local vars

    public Test() {
        super(Activity_Under_Test.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();

        instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
        context = instrumentation.getTargetContext();
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(...);
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.finish();
        }

        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void test1() {
        ... // change shared preferences so that Activity_ABC is started automatically from Activity_Under_Test

        monitor1 = instrumentation.addMonitor(Activity_ABC.class.getName(), null, false);

        activity = getActivity();

        // Activity_Under_Test starts automatically Activity_ABC and destroys itself
        activityABC = (Activity_ABC) mInstrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor1, 5);
        assertNotNull(activityABC);

        instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(activityABC);
            }
        });

        assertTrue(activityABC.isDestroyed());
        instrumentation.removeMonitor(monitor1);
    }

    public void test2() {
        ... // change shared preferences so that Activity_DEF is started automatically from Activity_Under_Test

        monitor2 = instrumentation.addMonitor(Activity_DEF.class.getName(), null, false);

        activity = getActivity();

        // Activity_Under_Test starts automatically Activity_DEF and destroys itself
        activityDEF = (Activity_DEF) mInstrumentation.waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor2, 5);
        assertNotNull(activityDEF);

        instrumentation.runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(activityDEF);
            }
        });

        assertTrue(activityDEF.isDestroyed());
        instrumentation.removeMonitor(monitor2);
    }
}
```

If you need more information, please tell me what I shall tell more.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show what you have tried..

Comment: I updated my first post to give you an idea what I am doing.